# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'hadi'@'localhost'

Tags: laravel

currently I install laravel 8 in my Linux operating system without any error, so I started working on a simple blog-post application, and when I run `php artisan migrate` I get the following error.

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'hadi'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 671▕             throw new QueryException(
    672▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673▕             );
    674▕         }
    675▕ 

      +34 vendor frames 
  35  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I search for my problem here and other sites but I can't find an exact solution.
Hope to get one

Comment: Make sure the database credentials defined in you `.env` file is correct. Check if you can login to your database using `phpmyadmin` or whatever.

Comment: yes I can login to mysql database as the user I set. I am sure there is no problem with my database.

Comment: This problem because your database credential at your .env

Comment: @SokChanty how can I solve it?

Comment: Make sure put correct database name, username, and password at here.

Comment: I did it correctly, using that username and password I can log in to MySQL databases

Comment: If so, delete Cache file at root/bootstrap/cache/file. and re-run the app.

Answer (score 1):

Check your file .env. Make sure its correctly.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_database_name
DB_USERNAME=your_username
DB_PASSWORD=your_password
```

In case, you put correct credential but it still not work you can:

**Delete Cache Files From root/boostrap/chache/files and Run The App**

Comment: I mean you have to manually delete the cache file at your project directory.

Comment: I already use these commands to clear my cache  [php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear]

Comment: Do you see bootstrap folder inside your project?

Comment: yes I can see it, delete the whole folder or just the cache?

Comment: So, delete cache/files it and re-run app again

Comment: I got this error this time " The /home/hadi/Desktop/blog/bootstrap/cache directory must be present and w  
  ritable.   "

Comment: sudo chmod -R 777 bootstrap/cache/

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me but I got the first issue :)  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'hadi'@'localhost'